# Proving an imprimitive group can be embedded in a wreath product

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, wreath-product

I came across this theorem here:https://cameroncounts.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/lect2n.pdf. However it is stated without proof and I'm not really sure where to start, any hints would be appreciated!

Let $G$ be a transitive but imprimitive permutation group on $Ω$. Let $Γ$ be a block of imprimitivity,
and $H$ the permutation group induced on $Γ$ by its setwise stabiliser; let $∆$ be an index set for the set of blocks
of imprimitivity, and let $K$ be the permutation group
induced on $∆$ by $G$.
Then there is a bijection between $Ω$ and $Γ × ∆$ under
which $G$ is embedded as a subgroup of $H \wr K$ (with its
imprimitive action).

Comment: I found a proof [here](https://www.math.colostate.edu/~hulpke/lectures/m666/hw8.pdf)